# Disable background transparency in (neo)vim

Tags: vim, transparency, opacity, konsole

I'm running Neovim 0.2.1 in Konsole with i3 and Compton in the back. I'm using a little bit of transparency in Konsole for a more dapper experience, but given that I use vim as my primary editor I'd prefer to not have transparency there as it's a little bit distracting. My colour scheme is [vim-monokai](https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai).

What's really got me scratching my head is that I have two computers, both running virtually the same setup (Intel integrated graphics, i3, Compton, Konsole, zsh, same neovim version and plugins). One does not have transparency in its terminal, while the other does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For vim:

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=Black
highlight NonText ctermbg=Black
```

Your colorschema most likely does not set ctermbg. Replace "Black" with the desired background color.

Comment: This kind of does it. I tried this and looked further and found the following:

* In QTerminal + Neovim, my theme displayed as intended. However, the commands did not change the background to black.
* In QTerminal + Vim, the background changing works as intended and disables transparency.
* In Konsole + Neovim, the commands did not work, as was the case before.
* In Konsole + Vim, the commands did not work, background stayed transparent per default theme.
* In Xfce's terminal emulator + Vim, the commands work as expected.
* In Xfce's terminal emulator + nvim, the commands do not work.

Comment: All in all this seems to point at my Qt environment being up to no good, my theme clashing somewhat with these commands in Nvim, but otherwise working as expected. As Vim/Neovim is evidently not the issue here, I'm marking this solved and dig further